# Check if all values in the same index among several lists are false

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of boolean values. I'm trying to return a list of indexes where all values in the same positions are only False. So in the example below, position `3` and `4` of each inner list are False, so return `[3,4]`.

Some assumptions to keep in mind, the list of lists could contain X number of lists, so can't rely on just three, it could be 50. Also, the inner lists will always have equal lengths, so no worrying about different-sized lists, but they could be longer than 6 like in the example I gave. So the solution must work for dynamic sizes/lengths.

```
list1 = [True, True, True, False, False, False]
list2 = [True, True, False, False, False, False]
list3 = [True, True, True, False, False, True]

list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3]

result_list_of_all_false_indexes = []

# Pseudo code
# Look in position 0 of each list in the list of lists. If they're all false
# result_list_of_all_false_indexes.append(index)

# Look in position 1 of each list in the list of lists. If they're all false
# result_list_of_all_false_indexes.append(index)

# continue for entire length of inner lists

assert result_list_of_all_false_indexes == [3,4], "Try again..."
```

Comment: Is `numpy` an option for you? If so, you could convert your list of lists into an array and apply `.all` to it.

Comment: This is possible to do, yes!

Comment: I am on the phone, so can't provide the answer but  guess you can figure it out with this hint :) good luck! To get the actual indices you would then also have to use `np.where` after using `all`.

Comment: Yes when using `.any`. `all` equates to ALL values being TRUE, which in this case, I needed to flip to FALSE. I was trying to make use of `not` or `!` when attempting `all`, but didn't work haha so I just used that. I posted the answer I used with this below. Thanks! @Cleb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from numpy, we can check your conditions by axis:

```
import numpy as np

results = np.where(~np.any(list_of_lists, axis=0))[0].tolist()

# Output:
[3, 4]
```

Comment: This is very close to the answer I posted, but I forgot to convert to a list again haha. Thanks! Very good solution!

Comment: My original thought was `(~np.any(list_of_lists, axis=0)).nonzero()[0].tolist()`, but I saw you'alls comments and swapped to use `np.where`

Answer (score 2):

I would use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) to unpack the `list_of_lists` and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indexes. Then the [any](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#any) function can be used with `not` to test for all `False` values.

```py
import random
n_lists = random.randrange(1, 20)
n_elements = random.randrange(3, 10)

# I set the relative weights to favor getting all False entries
list_of_lists = [
    random.choices([True, False], k=n_elements, weights=[1, 10])
    for i in range(n_lists)
]

result_list_of_all_false_indexes = [i for i, vals in enumerate(zip(*lol)) if not any(vals)]
```

Answer (score 2):

lol - list of lists
output - returns desired list of indexes.

```
def output(lol):
    res = []
    if lol:  # Checks if list contains any list at all
        res = [i for i in range(len(lol[0]))]
        for list_ in lol:
            res = [i for i in res if not list_[i]]
            if not res:
                break

    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
result_list_of_all_false_indexes = []
for i in range(len(list_of_lists[0])):
    if not any(lst[i] for lst in list_of_lists):
      
  result_list_of_all_false_indexes.append(i)
```

EDIT: added explanation

Iterate over each possible index, and then check if each list at that index is False. If so, add the index to your results list.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cleb in the comments, I was able to make this work:

```
from numpy import where, any

list1 = [True, True, True, False, False, False]
list2 = [True, True, False, False, False, False]
list3 = [True, True, True, False, False, True]

list_of_lists = [list1, list2, list3]

result = where(np.any(list_of_lists, axis=0) == False)[0]
print(result)

assert result == [3,4], "Try again..."
```

Rather than using `all` (which evaluates to ALL values on a certain access are `True`) I used `any` and `==False` to accomplish what I was after.

It fails the assertion as it's now in an array format (not list separated by commas), but that's fine with me. A little more concise than having to use iteration, but either will work. Thanks all!